# Encriptar Cadena de conexion en launchSettings.Json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-8.0

actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto .net core y tengo una libreria de clases C# que hace una conexion con la base de datos para obtener algunos resultados. Los parametros de conexion los tengo almacenados en el archivo **launchSettings.json** lo que quiero saber es como puedo encriptar los datos de conexion o cual seria la logica para que fuera una conexion segura. Muchas gracias por su ayuda:

**launchSettings.json**

```
 "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    
    "CadenaConexion": "server=*******;port=3306;database=*********;Uid=root;password=*******"

  }
},
```

clase que Hace la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué cifrar? Si un atacante puede acceder al sistema de archivos y leer un archivo que podría protegerse con permisos para que solo un usuario administrativo lo lea, creo que se está ante un problema aún más grave.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Solucione este problema con la libreria chustasoft.Tools.SecureConfig permite encryptar los datos que uno considere necesario en el archivo config.json